# Will CSS parsing errors cause problems in a production environment?

Tags: css, production-environment, production, parse-error, text-size

I got this error in CSS:

```
Error in parsing value for '-webkit-text-size-adjust'. Declaration dropped.
```

The only way I can get rid of it is to remove the property, which I can't do since I need it for my `reset.css` file.

If I push this update, will this CSS parsing error cause my site to break? I'm testing in FireFox 67 and so far nothing is breaking because of this, is this also the case for other browsers?

Comment: not too much...

Comment: This is a vendor-prefixed property. Browsers who don’t understand it, are supposed to simply ignore this declaration. This should not “break” anything.

Comment: It's still a common practice to use fallback styles exactly for cases like this and for the 5 people who still use IE9 or any other outdated browsers versions, so I agree with the first comment - I wouldn't be worried too much about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is intrinsic to vendor identifiers (those that begin with '_' or '-'): only its product will understand them, so every other one should ignore them. In fact, CSS rules for parsing errors mandate implementers to ignore them: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/syndata.html#parsing-errors